# Iterations to Recursion Scheme: Dr. Racket

Tags: racket

Help, I wrote 6 iterations of arm rotation, but I want to write this function recursively. Does anyone have any tips?

```
(: rotate-arm : Image Image Natural -> Image)

;; rotates the entire arm 5 times, returning the full star

(define (rotate-arm tile tile2 i)
  (local 
      {(define arm (draw-arm tile tile2 i))}
    (clear-pinhole
     (overlay/pinhole
       (put-pinhole 
         (center-x (draw-arm tile tile2 i)) 0 arm)
       (rotate (* i 60) (put-pinhole 
                          (center-x arm) 0 arm))
       (rotate 60 (put-pinhole 
                    (center-x arm) 0 arm))
       (rotate 120 (put-pinhole 
                    (center-x arm) 0 arm))
       (rotate 180 (put-pinhole 
                    (center-x arm) 0 arm))
       (rotate 240 (put-pinhole 
                    (center-x arm) 0 arm))
       (rotate 300 (put-pinhole 
                    (center-x arm) 0 arm))))))
```

It's correct, just inefficient.

Comment: What exactly do you want to make recursive?

Comment: I think it's about the DRY or "Don't Repeat Yourself" principle of programming. Currently almost the same code is repeated 6 times